# Entropy of an oscillator in Einstein's solid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, entropy, oscillators, atomic-excitation

This is a homework problem and I need help with it.

A solid's (Einstein's model) oscillators are in the first excited state on average. How much entropy does one oscillator have?

What I've tried so far:

So, the statistical sum is

$$Z=\sum_n \exp(\phi(n+1/2))$$

where $$\phi = \frac{h\nu}{kT}$$

And the entropy can be expressed as

$$S=k \frac{\partial}{\partial T}(T \ln Z)$$

We also know that

$$\bar n =\sum_n (n \exp(\phi(n+1/2))) = 1$$

I've managed to express

$$\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial \phi} = \bar n + 1/2$$

but this seems to be a dead end.

All tips and comments are welcome, thanks!

Comment: Please check the results (the compiled version of your text that appears below as you type), none of the expressions were rendered correctly.

Comment: Oh, sorry, to me they seemed OK, probably because of some browser plugin then. Thanks for the edit.